# How to create a VPN connection in Swift on OS X?

Tags: macos, swift, vpn

I followed the steps described in [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Macnetworkprog/2011/May/msg00032.html) tutorial.

I tried to translate the code from Objective-C to Swift. This is the code I have:

```
 var l2tpInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(
        kSCNetworkInterfaceIPv4,
        kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeL2TP
        ).takeUnretainedValue();
    var pppInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(
        l2tpInterface,
        kSCNetworkInterfaceTypePPP
        ).takeUnretainedValue();
    var prefs = SCPreferencesCreate(nil,"SoybeanVPN",nil).takeUnretainedValue();
    var service = SCNetworkServiceCreate(prefs, pppInterface).takeUnretainedValue();
    var success = SCNetworkServiceEstablishDefaultConfiguration(service);
```

This code returns a runtime error `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1)` at the first line.

I googled this error and someone said the problem is caused by using released object in Objective-C? Is that the same in Swift? Does anyone have any experience with VPN creation in Swift?

UPDATE:
I tried to debug and find the const value of `kSCNetworkInterfaceIPv4` is invalid, see the attached image:
[image]

Is that a bug of Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `kSCNetworkInterfaceIPv4` is not the problem, because I can use it just fine to create L2TP/IPSec and Cisco VPNs using Swift.

It's rather tricky to handle C pointers in Swift, but this is how I do it, using Swift 2.3. Notice the wrapping/unwrapping with `!` of C-Reference objects.

```
let initialTopInterface: SCNetworkInterfaceRef!
let initialBottomInterface: SCNetworkInterfaceRef!

// L2TP on top of IPv4
initialBottomInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(kSCNetworkInterfaceIPv4, kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeL2TP)
// PPP on top of L2TP
initialTopInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(initialBottomInterface!, kSCNetworkInterfaceTypePPP)

let service = SCNetworkServiceCreate(usingPreferencesRef, initialTopInterface!)

// Now you assign the attributes
SCNetworkServiceSetName(service, ("Some Name" as CFString))
// myConfiguration is a Hash with your relevant Key/Value pairs
SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration(topInterface!, myConfiguration)

// Here is a good example for why Swift may just crash if you're not careful
let temporaryString:CFString = "IPSec"
SCNetworkInterfaceSetExtendedConfiguration(topInterface!, temporaryString, myL2tpConfiguration)
SCNetworkServiceEstablishDefaultConfiguration(service)
```

You can find a working implementation (for macOS Sierra) [on Github](https://github.com/halo/macosvpn/blob/cefc8934057e32c463a4a3bd6b112c66149acfda/macosvpn/Classes/VPNServiceCreator.swift#L49)

Answer (score 0):

Just need copy all SCNetworkInterface's

```
SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()
```

Insert it at the beginning, before creating interfaces